# Overriding inline styles with media inquiries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit of small issue. As we are aware inline styles take priority of stylesheets. I am using Bootstrap and using the .alert .alert-danger .alert-success class in my layout for notifying status on a certain page. In one area I have applied an inline style as it is a one off for what I need it for in that section of my page to have more control for how I need it.

```
$divStyle = "padding:5px; width:50%; margin:auto; margin-bottom:20px";

<div class='alert alert-danger' style='{$divStyle}'...
```

This naturally works great on the desktop but, when I get on a mobile device the inline style takes priority off course and on mobile since I am using width 50% it  doesn't span the width of the screen anymore of course now. In the stylesheet since I am hosting the Bootstrap locally on my server so I can have more control I have added this.

```
    @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) { 
    .alert .alert-danger {
       width:100%;
}
}
```

Hoping that would override the inline style for mobile devices. Naturally that doesn't work as I slapped myself in the head as it won't work since the inline style will take priority and not to mention it is 100% width by default anyways regardless of the screen but, since I have applied an inline style, anything in the stylesheet is overwritten.

So my question is. Does anyone know of any trick that I can apply to override this inline style that will be applied to mobile devices without sacrificing the inline style for the desktop layout since you can't use media queries inline ether.

**EDIT**

I have tried adding the !important tag to the media query so it would take priority over the inline style on mobile devices but, it is still not overriding the inline style on mobile devices.

```
    @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) { 
    .alert .alert-danger {
       width:100% !important;
}
}
```

-Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove all inline rules, place them in a stylesheet and apply the `!important;` tag to them? I'm not a fan of this as it breaks the precedence rules. However, if you do that for the desktop styles, they'll take first precedence, followed by the mobile rules (also with `!important;`) which will take mobile precedence?...

Comment: If I did it that way I would probably have to create a completely new class but, let me play with that idea. I forgot about that tag since I don't ever use it.

Comment: @War10ck see my edited updated post above with what I tried.